# Git attribute core.autocrlf applies on clone, but not on checkout

Tags: git, line-endings, core.autocrlf

On Windows, if I clone a repo with `core.autocrlf false` which includes files with Unix (LF) line endings I get the Unix line endings as expected. Then, if I change this setting to `true` and checkout another branch in the repo I continue to see the `core.autocrlf false` behavior (ie Unix files still have `LF` line endings)

If I  clone the same repo with `core.autocrlf true` the line endings are converted to 'CRLF` as I would expect.

I confirmed that `core.autocrlf` was being set at all config levels. This behavior seems to be consistent on OS X as well.

From the [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration):

> If you’re on a Windows machine, set it to true – this converts LF endings into CRLF when you **check out** code

`core.autocrlf` does not seem to apply to any given checkout, but rather "inherits" from whatever the setting was when the local repo was cloned.

Is this expected behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Merely changing the configuration option does not rewrite your work tree. You need to do another `git checkout ...` before you'll see the effects, as `autocrlf` processing is done in the `checkout` and `add` paths. And, if you checkout a commit that only differs in a subset of the files, you will still only see partial "conversion". You could `rm -rf *; git checkout -f HEAD` to force `git` to rewrite everything...

Comment: I am doing a git checkout after I change the config, but I am not seeing the effects. You are suggesting it is because the files are not changing between branches? Makes sense, I guess. I will test this.